# What starts syslog and logrotate?

Tags: init.d

I was looking under `/etc/rc?.d` and I didn't see many scripts compared to the number of scripts in `/etc/init.d`.

I see `syslog` running on my machine but who started it ? No script in `/etc/rc?.d` point to it.

Also `logrotate` is not running (`ps aux | grep logrotate`) but it seems to be running. And if I look at its configuration I see it takes care of `rsyslog`.

Where does all the magic happen ?

Comment: What distribution and version are you using?

Comment: I have Ubuntu 12.04.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a `dpkg -L logrotate` should give you a clue about logrotate:

```
$ dpkg -L logrotate 
.
.
/etc/logrotate.d
/etc/logrotate.conf
/etc/cron.daily
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate
```

Which indicates `cron` starts logrotate (via the `anacron` entries in /etc/crontab).

`syslog` normally comes from the `rsyslog` package. (`man rsyslogd`)